# Is going to confession considered "good work" in the faith vs. work distinction in justification?

Tags: catholicism, confession, justification, works

A comment by a Catholic in a discussion with a Protestant about faith vs. good works startled me:

> Catholics would consider going to Confession to be a work. It's a specific act you need to do. We don't have any qualms about saying Christians need to do all kinds of works, except the works of the Law.

Of course confessing mortal sins are necessary for a Catholic to go back to the state of grace so they can **subsequently** do "good works" that are meritorious.  **That's not what at issue here.**  Secondly, although liturgy literally means "public work", I'm excluding that meaning here since "work" here seems to refer to what the Church is doing on behalf or for the benefit of the people.  I'm thus not asking about the "work" done by the priests to assist a faithful's going to confession but asking **whether it is considered "good work" for the penitent**.

So, within the debate with Protestants on salvation, am I wrong in saying that going to the Sacrament of Confession is technically *not* "good works" even if it's necessary to restore the state of grace in order to do "good works" for our salvation?  For this question I'm defining "good work" in the sense described by this *Catholic Answers* article [Are Good Works Necessary for Salvation?](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/are-good-works-necessary-for-salvation)

In my understanding of Catholicism, good works are works of love flowing out of faith and powered by grace; works that are meritorious, which God counts toward the final justification of a believer in the state of grace.

**So my question is**: According to Catholicism, is going to confession considered "good work" that increases one's righteousness, when considered from the angle that the sacrament merely **enable** us to perform works of love, the LATTER being the meritorious acts contributing to the increase of righteousness (for final justification)?

Comment: How does participating in a Sacrament not meet the definition of good work you proposed here?

Comment: @jaredad7 I clarified the question to highlight possible differences between "work" that a Catholic does in going to confession / mass vs. "work of love" performed to our neighbors.

Comment: Are you separating the instant of the appearance of the sacrament for the liturgy? Because liturgy is literally work.

Comment: @PeterTurner Good point.  Yes, liturgy is "public work", but in my Q I'm specifically asking for a believer's *participation* in liturgy, and whether soteriologically it's called "good work" or not.  Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @PeterTurner I maybe wrong in my understanding of "work" in Catholicism.  If you don't separate the merit of participating in the liturgy from the merit of doing works of love for our neighbors, then yes, it makes sense that participating in the liturgy counts as "work".  My instinct says there is a difference because in polemical / apologetical articles discussing faith vs. work with Protestants, I have never seen going to liturgy / confession included in the discussion.

Comment: @gra have you heard of the Corporal Works of Mercy and the Spiritual Works of Mercy?

Comment: @PeterTurner [Here's a good summary](https://fwdioc.org/works-of-mercy.pdf).  Of course a priest in celebrating the mass will do several of the spiritual works of mercy.  I'm asking about from the congregation's side. 
 Just in case going to mass IS considered "work" (for the congregation, let's say in praying for spiritual need of their neighbors) that incur merit soteriologically, do you think it makes a difference restricting this question to confession only?

Comment: @PeterTurner I found the support for how going to mass (as faithful) is also meritorious "work" (see point D in the article [The Merit of a Mass](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~aversa/modernism/Merit%20of%20the%20Mass%20(Fr.%20Ripperger,%20F.S.S.P.).pdf) by Fr. Chad Ripperger, FSSP).  Therefore, I changed the scope to "going to confession" only.  It's interesting that Msgr. Pohle lump together the congregation **as well as** the "true" workers: priests, singers, organist, servers, etc.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple yeah, I think it makes a world of difference to limit to confession only.  Other than the work of maybe setting a good example for your kids, going to Confession is between you and Jesus entirely; Preparing for confession includes several spiritual works of Mercy, doing your penance is more work.  But the act of confession itself is something different.  That's why I thought you were talking about something the moment in the Mass where you receive communion or the epiclesis (where we believe Jesus truly becomes present in the Eucharist)

Comment: @PeterTurner OK.  So the comment I cited is correct, then.  I hope the answer can describe the preparatory spiritual works of mercy and how the penance is meritorious (as opposed to works simply to pay the horizontal penalty of your sins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific works in going to confession are bolded:

1. **Examining** your conscience
2. **Waiting** in line
3. **Saying** your sins
4. **Listening** to advice
5. **Praying** an "act of contrition"
6. **Thanking** your priest
7. **Doing** your penance

Each of these things can be done well or poorly and the penitent still receives the same measure of forgiveness (i.e. is brought back in to the same state of grace).

> The infusion of grace suffices for the remission of sin;
>
> https://www.newadvent.org/summa/5006.htm#article1

Doing them well can form a good habit (i.e. a virtue) and thereby increase ones receptivity to grace; especially actual grace to go and do more good works.

I wish St. Thomas were around to offer a *distinguo* as to whether only confessing once a year was a "work of the law" because it is a precept of the Church.  He does say that we're bound to go to confession once a year if only to confess venial sins.

Now, if I were to put on my dumb ox cap, I can reason out that *that work* would not save you because in the unlikely event that you remain in a state of grace throughout the whole year and only confess venial sins, the work would not save you - but the neglect of the work would condemn you.

Therefore, it seems rational to call the whole thing a "good work" since it fits the bill as

1. Inspired by the movement of grace
2. Essential for salvation of fallen human beings
3. Has elements which may or may not be meritorious based on ones disposition

Comment: I see my blind spot now: I was focusing only on the mortal sin aspect.  Framed this way, the act of *preparing* to confess venial sins, if done *well*, increases virtue since it increases one's receptivity to grace, which in turn helps one to do more good works.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple yeah, confessing mortal sins is like a going to the hospital for an  appendectomy so you can not die; confessing venial sins is like going to the clinic for a physical so you can go play baseball.

Comment: If it is a good work, the question then remains as to whether it is a good work *unto* salvation or a good work *resulting from* salvation.  Paul says the former is impossible and only acknowledges the latter (Ephesians 2:8-10).